# Get all documents matching a query in vespa

Tags: vespa

I have total 1600 documents in vespa but using query I am only able to get 400 documents as there is limit of 400 in vespa. How can I get all documents using query in vespa or is there any other way to to do this. Here is the query I am using:

https://localhost:8080/search/?yql=select * from sources * where default contains "7eNMedftCqkKoaw"  limit 400;

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, by default the maximum number of hits you can get for a query is 400 as you have noticed. You can change this by adding a query profile (https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-api-reference.html#queryProfile) with the setting "maxHits" to whatever you like.

See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/query-profiles.html for information on how to add query profiles.

Comment: Suppose I set maxHits to 500 and I shall able to get 500 documents but how can I get next 500 documents if total documents is 1500?

Comment: You can use the offset query parameter: https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-api-reference.html#offset